# MonacaでWikitudeプラグインを使ってARアプリを作る方法

Tags: monaca

「MonacaでWikitudeプラグインを使ってARアプリを作る」https://ja.onsen.io/blog/monaca-with-wikitude/　に従って，monaca でwikitudeプラグインを使ってARアプリを作っているのですが、
Androidで確認したところ以下のエラーが発生し、処理がいきません。

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: wikitudePlugin is not defined  www/js/index.js:13
```

また、ソース類は以下のようになっております。

【plugin.xml】

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
id="com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin"
version="5.3.0">

<name>Augmented Reality - Wikitude SDK Plugin</name>

<author>Wikitude GmbH</author>
<keywords>AR,augmented reality,Wikitude,image recognition,cloud       recognition</keywords>

<description>
    The Wikitude PhoneGap Plugin enables developers to embed an augmented reality view into their PhoneGap project. You can create a fully featured app with advanced augmented reality features, including image recognition, purely using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
</description>

<repo>https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap.git</repo>

<license>(c) 2016 Wikitude GmbH - see License.md for details of the license</license>


<engines>
  <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.0.0" />
</engines>  

<!-- copy WikitudePlugin wrapper file into www-folder -->
<js-module src="www/WikitudePlugin.js" name="WikitudePlugin">
    <clobbers target="WikitudePlugin" />
</js-module>

<!-- android -->
<platform name="android">

    <!-- declare implementation of WikitudePlugin -->
    <source-file src="src/android/WikitudePlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/wikitude/phonegap" />

    <!-- copy build extras, necessary for wikitude.aar -->
    <source-file src="src/android/libs/build-extras.gradle" target-dir="." />

    <!-- add permissions and requirements -->
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass" android:required="true" />
    </config-file>

    <!-- adds MediaPlayerActivity, required for startVideo feature-->
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
        <activity android:name="com.wikitude.tools.activities.MediaPlayerActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </config-file>


    <!-- copy wikitude sdk -->
    <source-file src="src/android/libs/wikitudesdk.aar" target-dir="libs/" />


    <!-- adds WikitudePlugin in project's config.xml -->
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="WikitudePlugin">
            <param name="android-package" value="com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>


    <!-- visible after installation -->
    <info>
        Have fun using world's first AR plugin for PhoneGap. Visit http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/phonegap for detailed documentation for the plugin.

        Make sure that you enter your Wikitude SDK trial license key in `WikitudePlugin.js` line 12. If you havent bought a license please visit http://www.wikitude.com/store.

        If you want to contribute to the open source project, please visit us at github, http://github.com/Wikitude
    </info>



</platform>

<!-- iOS -->
<platform name="ios">


    <!-- WikitudePlugin Source -->
    <header-file src="src/ios/WTWikitudePlugin.h" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/WTWikitudePlugin.m" />

    <header-file src="src/ios/WTARViewController.h" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/WTARViewController.m" />

    <header-file src="src/ios/WikitudeSDK.h" />
    <header-file src="src/ios/WTArchitectView.h" />
    <header-file src="src/ios/WTNavigation.h" />
    <header-file src="src/ios/WTStartupConfiguration.h" />
    <header-file src="src/ios/WTArchitectViewDebugDelegate.h" />
    <header-file src="src/ios/WTWikitudeTypes.h" />

    <source-file src="src/ios/libWikitudeSDK.a" framework="true" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/libWikitudeSDK-simulator.a" framework="true" />


    <!-- Additional WikitudePlugin libraries and frameworks -->
    <framework src="Accelerate.framework" />
    <framework src="AssetsLibrary.framework" />
    <framework src="AVFoundation.framework" />
    <framework src="CFNetwork.framework" />
    <framework src="CoreGraphics.framework" />
    <framework src="CoreLocation.framework" />
    <framework src="CoreMedia.framework" />
    <framework src="CoreMotion.framework" />
    <framework src="CoreText.framework" />
    <framework src="CoreVideo.framework" />
    <framework src="Foundation.framework" />
    <framework src="MediaPlayer.framework" />
    <framework src="OpenGLES.framework" />
    <framework src="QuartzCore.framework" />
    <framework src="Security.framework" />
    <framework src="SystemConfiguration.framework" />
    <framework src="UIKit.framework" />  
    <framework src="libc++.dylib" />
    <framework src="libz.dylib" />


    <!-- Adopts project's config.xml to include the WikitudePlugin and domain white-lists -->
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="WikitudePlugin">
            <param name="ios-package" value="WTWikitudePlugin"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>


    <!-- visible after installation -->
    <info>
        Have fun using world's first AR plugin for PhoneGap. Visit http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/phonegap for detailed documentation for the plugin.

        Make sure that you enter your Wikitude SDK trial license key in `WikitudePlugin.js` line 53. If you havent bought a license please visit http://www.wikitude.com/store.

        If you want to contribute to the open source project, please visit us at github, http://github.com/Wikitude
    </info>

</platform>
```

【index.html】

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br />
This is a template for Monaca app.
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

【index.js】

```
var app = {
// 初期化
initialize: function() {
this.bindEvents();
},
// イベントの設定
bindEvents: function() {
document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady, false);
},

// 準備完了になったら呼ばれます
onDeviceReady: function() {
wikitudePlugin.isDeviceSupported(
  app.onDeviceSupported,
    app.onDeviceNotSupported,
    [ "2d_tracking"]
 );
 },

// ARをサポートしている場合に実行
onDeviceSupported: function() {
wikitudePlugin.loadARchitectWorld(
  app.onARExperienceLoadedSuccessful, 
  app.onARExperienceLoadError,
  "www/ar.html",
  [ "2d_tracking"],
  {"camera_position": "back"}
 );
},

// デバイスがサポートしていない場合
onDeviceNotSupported: function(errorMessage) {
alert(errorMessage);
},

// ARを読み込んだ場合のコールバック
onARExperienceLoadedSuccessful: function(loadedURL) {
},

// ARを読み込めなかった場合のエラーコールバック
onARExperienceLoadError: function(errorMessage) {
alert('Loading AR web view failed: ' + errorMessage);
}
};

app.initialize();
```

【www/ar.html】

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=5,user-scalable=yes" name="viewport">

<title></title>

<script src="architect://architect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ade.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
</head>

<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

【www/ar.html】

```
var World = {
loaded: false,

// 初期化処理
init: function initFn() {
    this.createOverlays();
},

// オーバーレイ表示する指定
createOverlays: function createOverlaysFn() {
    this.tracker = new AR.ClientTracker("assets/magazine.wtc");
    var imgOne = new AR.ImageResource("assets/imageOne.png");
    var overlayOne = new AR.ImageDrawable(imgOne, 1, {
        offsetX: -0.15,
        offsetY: 0
    });
    var pageOne = new AR.Trackable2DObject(this.tracker, "*", {
        drawables: {
            cam: overlayOne
        }
    });
  }

};

World.init();
```

お手数おかけいたしますが、
この問題を解決する方法をお教えください、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「MonacaでWikitudeプラグインを使ってARアプリを作る」の記事を最初から最後まで目を通しましたか？

Comment: 目を通すことは何度もしましたが，コードの意味をしっかり理解できているかというと，理解不足のところは多々あります．

Comment: 非常に分かりやすく，丁寧に書かれているので，その通りやっていけばできるのではないかと思っているのですが，どこが間違っているのかわからず，申し訳ありません．index.jsの中のwikitudePluginの前に何か書かなければいけないのではないかと考えているですが，知識不足でよくわからないのです．

Comment: ベーシックプランなので試すことができませんが、ゴールドプランか？Wikitudeプラグインのインポートを行ったか？Wikitudeプラグインの編集を行ったか？ビルドして実行したか？ということです。

Comment: ゴールドプランです．Wikitudeプラグインのインポートをしたつもりです．「Cordovaとプラグインの設定」のページで，有効なプラグインに「Augmented Reality Wikitude SDK Plugin」が入っているのでできているのではないかと思います．WikitudePlugin.jsの中で，"YOUR LICENSE  HERE"の部分にライセンスキーを入れました．デバッグビルドをして，アプリケーションを作成しました．

Comment: ライセンスキーを書き換えて行末まで移動してグローバルオブジェクトにしましたか？